# Read from "output" as from "input"

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, symbian, maemo

Some on of you saw [this](https://squareup.com/features).

So the question is, how to access mobile audio out in read mode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fundamentally impossible, at least from the level of a software application (it could be possible in hardware or even firmware).  That device works by taking advantage of the microphone jack included in the headphone jack.  The hardware communicates with the application via an audio signal that is read from the microphone input.

Comment: Again, Android also has a microphone jack as part of it's headphone jack.  It is what allows you to connect a physical headphone set with a microphone to the device.  Notice there isn't an iPod Touch model?  That's because the iPod touch doesn't have a microphone jack.  Like I said, it is impossible to capture audio from the "output" connector.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't the answer you were looking for!